# For loop and columns in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I am new in PL/SQL. I have a problem with loop in this language. I' d like to make loop like this:

```
FOR nr IN 1..102 
LOOP
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nr);
  IF rec.column_||nr IS NULL
    THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('test');
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

I have created a cursor. As you can see I' d like to check all column with names column from column_1 to column_102. Unfortunately || operator does not work for this situation. 
Do you know some solution to my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with [dynamic PL/SQL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm). Use an [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm) statement to execute a string argument as PL/SQL, which you can make up with `||` as it was intended in the question.

Example:

```
BEGIN 
    FOR nr IN 1..102 
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nr);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
            'BEGIN ' || 
            'IF rec.column.' || nr ||' is null THEN ' ||
                'DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(''test''); ' ||
            'END IF; ' || 
            'END; ';
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Or you could also assign `rec.column.' || nr ||' is null` to a variable and make the `PUT_LINE` outside the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` part:

**UPDATE**: It seems it is not possible to bind `BOOLEAN` variables, so I've modified the example to use a `NUMBER`.

**UPDATE 2:** There is a possible efficiency improvement, altough maybe not suitable in this case. Use a constant `VARCHAR` for the dynamic SQL, and pass in `nr` with a binded variable. This is even more efficient than using native SQL if in a large loop. I don't think `'rec.column.:arg is null` would execute as `'rec.column.1 is null`, though.

```
 DECLARE
    isnull NUMBER;
 BEGIN 
    FOR nr IN 1..102 
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nr);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
            'BEGIN ' || 
                'IF rec.column.' || nr ||' IS NULL THEN ' || 
                    ':x:=1; ' || 
                'ELSE ' ||
                    ':x:=0; ' ||
                'END IF; ' ||
            'END; ' 
            USING OUT isnull;
        IF isnull = 1 THEN 
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('test');
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

---

**UPDATE 3**: 
Seeing that:

- It is not possible to access `rec` inside the dynamic SQL statement because it is undefined (out of scope),
- It seems not possible to pass a non-sql type as an argument to the dynamic statement (record, cursor)

A possible workaround is to bind some id columns (SQL Type) to the dynamic statement, and use a `select` clause to find out if the current column is null:

```
DECLARE
        isnull NUMBER;
        rec_id NUMBER; -- Identifier of the fetched record
     BEGIN 
        rec_id := rec.id;
        FOR nr IN 1..102 
        LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nr);
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
                'SELECT 1 FROM my_table WHERE id = :idarg ' ||
                   ' AND column_' || nr || ' IS NULL'
              INTO isnull USING rec_id;
            IF isnull = 1 THEN 
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('test');
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    END;
```

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: Unfortunately BOOLEAN is not sql type, and I get an error because of that.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, as explained [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#BHCEJIDC). I just figured this out while testing it. I've updated the example to use a `NUMBER` instead.

Comment: I have now another problem, maybe you can help me with it too. When I try to run my procedure with the above code. I get this error:  PLS-00201: identifier 'rec.column_1' must be declared. This problem appears with line "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE..."

Comment: This error is happening because `rec` is undefined and out of scope in the dynamic SQL. It has no easy workaround that I know of, maybe you should be binding some kind of identifier (with SQL Types) to the dynamic SQL and using a `select` clause. See the updated answer and let me know if this is suitable to you.

Comment: I' ve solve this with 'rec  user.table_test%ROWTYPE; ' in DECLARE inside EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Comment: @user987903 Are you sure this works propely? Have you checked that the `rec` variable inside the dynamic statement has the values of the `rec` outside it? It seems like the `rec` inside the dynamic statement is a new variable with all fields `null`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4531/discussion-between-xavi-lopez-and-user987903)